# JQuery show hide, not showing second div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Jquery show hide script that i have been using fine, i now want to add in a second div to show hide..

first div still shows and hides as it should however the second div hides but wont show..

code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.slidingDiv').hide();
  $('#show_hide').show();
  $('.equipdetailupload').hide();
  $('#show_hide2').show();

  $('#show_hide').click(function() {

    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    var isvisible = $(this).next('.slidingDiv').is(':visible');

    if (isvisible) {
      $(this).next('.slidingDiv').hide();
    } else {
      $(this).next('.slidingDiv').show();
    }
  });


  $('#show_hide2').click(function() {

    $(".equipdetailupload").slideToggle();
    var isvisible = $(this).next('.equipdetailupload').is(':visible');

    if (isvisible) {
      $(this).next('.equipdetailupload').hide();
    } else {
      $(this).next('.equipdetailupload').show();
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id='show_hide2' href='#'>upload Image</a>
<p class='equipdetailupload'></p>
<---------------------see notes <div class='equipdetailupload'>
  <!-- #INCLUDE virtual="imageup/uploadtester1.asp" -->
  </div>
```

Notes:
The line marked with see notes i added as a test while trying to get the div to show, with that line in the div also shows without it the code doesnt work

Comment: can u provide ur html

Comment: Please also provide your HTML and if applicable your CSS code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: As side note: you can get rid of your visibility check and if-else function by using .toggle() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this working now, solution is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.slidingDiv').hide();
    $('#show_hide').show();
    $('.equipdetailupload').hide();
    $('#show_hide2').show();

    $('#show_hide').click(function() {

         $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
         var isvisible = $(this).next('.slidingDiv').is(':visible');

         if ( isvisible ) {
           $(this).next('.slidingDiv').hide();
         } else{
           $(this).next('.slidingDiv').show();
         }
    });


    $('#show_hide2').click(function() {

         $(".equipdetailupload").slideToggle();
         var isvisible = $(this).next('.equipdetailupload').is(':visible');

         if ( isvisible ) {
           $(this).next('.equipdetailupload').hide();
         } else{
           $(this).next('.equipdetailupload').show();
         }
    });
    $('#show_hide3').click(function() {

         $(".equipdetailupload1").slideToggle();
         var isvisible = $(this).next('.equipdetailupload1').is(':visible');

         if ( isvisible ) {
           $(this).next('.equipdetailupload1').hide();
         } else{
           $(this).next('.equipdetailupload1').show();
         }
    });

});
</script>
```